# How do i make my game object goes to that specific direction after it bounces off a collision and not behave erratically?

Tags: unity, c#

```
 public class Ball : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speedBall = 200f;
    Rigidbody2D rbBall;

    private void Awake()
    {
        rbBall = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }
    private void Start()
    {
        addStartingForce();
    }
    private void Update()
    {
        
    }

    void addStartingForce()
    {
        float x = Random.value < 0.5f ? -1f : 1f; //less than half, go negative. Greater than half, go positive
        float y = Random.value < 0.5f ? Random.Range(-1f, -0.5f) : Random.Range(0.5f, 1f);

        Vector2 direction = new Vector2(x, y);
        rbBall.AddForce(direction * speedBall);
    }

    public void addforce(Vector2 force)
    {
        rbBall.AddForce(force);
    }

    void HeadingTowards()
    {
        Vector2 Dir = new Vector2(-50f, 0f);
        rbBall.AddForce(Dir * speedBall);
    }

    private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        if(collision.gameObject.CompareTag("wall"))
        {
            HeadingTowards();
        }
    }
}
```

Now once it bounces off a wall, it sometimes head towards my ("HeadingTowards") direction which was intended but after each bounce it didn't and the speed goes crazy fast unless I put time.deltaTime which I was told to not put it on addforce.

[image]

Comment: Am I understanding that you always want the ball to bounce left when it hits the wall, no matter what its incident angle was?

Comment: like when it goes more positive, it will bounce to the right. But when it goes negative, it will bounce to that specific direction

Comment: Hmm... it might help if you include a diagram showing a few different incoming bounces, and what you want the outgoing bounce to look like in each case. I'm not confident I understand your goal from the text description so far.

Comment: ok have edited to post a pic for example haha. Basically I want that object to bounce and no matter where it collides with, it will bounce off and goes right onto that one position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you just want to bend the velocity to aim at a specific position, not add a force. So, don't add a force, just set the velocity.

```
void HeadingTowards(Vector2 targetPosition)
{
    Vector2 Dir = (targetPosition - rbBall.position).normalized;
    rbBall.velocity(Dir * speedBall);
}
```

Comment: thank you so much!